# passing jquery args from custom attribute to $.get

Tags: jquery, variables

I need help with little, trivious thing:

```
<div data-link='somephpfile' data-vars='{ testvar: "blablabla" }' ...
```

Now, I'm getting this **data-vars** to a javascript **var**, like that:

```
var variables = $(this).attr("data-vars");
```

So far, so good :-)
Now, when I want to use this variables, like below...

```
$.get( "file.php", variables, function() {} ....
```

...it doesn't work. I guess, the way I am passing those variables, are not the correct method. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you should parse your JSON string before using it inside you `get` function, but this won't work either since your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `data-vars` attribute contains JSON string, you probably meant it to be de-serialized for you. For this, you'll need to use `data()` instead:

```
var variables = $(this).data("vars");
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: But I need to use different variable names each time, and different data. Is there any way to get "custom" var names with .data function?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? Send this JSON to the server?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
json_encode($(this).attr("data-vars"));
```

Comment: This would be `json_decode` then. The javascript equivalent is `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Yes! **JSON.parse**! It works perfectly! :-))))) Thank you a lot!